# Convex optimization lagrange multiplier nash bargaining problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, game-theory, lagrange-multiplier

I have an optimization problem that looks like this:

let $\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
 x_{0,0} & x_{0,1} \ ... & x_{0,L}\\ 
x_{1,0} & x_{1,1} \ ... & x_{1,L}\\
\vdots \\
x_{K,0} & x_{K,1} \ ... & x_{K,L}\\
\end{bmatrix}$

$\max_{\mathbf{X}} \sum_{L}\ln\phi_{L}$
where  $\phi_{L} = \sum_{k} q_{k,L}x_{k, L}$,

$\sum_{L} x_{k,L} = N_{k}$

and $d_{L}\leq\phi_{L}$

$x_{k,L}$ being free variables, $d_{L}, q_{k,L}, N_{k}$ being constants.

I've tried solving with the LaGrange multiplier method, the lagrangian then became:

$\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{X}) = \sum_{L}\ln\phi_{L} + \sum_{k}\lambda_{k}\left(N_{k} - \sum_{L} x_{k,l}\right) + \sum_{L}m_{L}(\phi_{L}-d_{L}) $,

deriving and equalling to zero:

$\partial_{x_{k,L}}\mathcal{L} = 0 = \frac{q_{k,L}}{\phi_{L}} -\lambda_{k}  + m_{L}q_{k,L} $

isolating $\phi_{L}$:

$\phi_{L} = \frac{q_{k,L}}{\lambda_{k} - q_{k,L} m_{L}}$

the KKT conditions being:

$m_{L}(d_{L} - \phi_{L}) = 0$ and

The problems arise when we perceive that the $\phi_{L}$ depends only on the variable L, but the RHS depends on k and L. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: But, $\phi_{L} = \sum_{k} q_{k,L}x_{k, L}$ so $\phi_{L}$ is dependent on $q_{k,L}$ and $x_{k,L}$.

Comment: What i've meant  to say is that it doesn't depend on a specific pick of k, because of the sum, so $\phi_{L} = \frac{q_{k,L}}{\lambda_{k} + q_{k,L}(M_{L} - m_{L})} =  \frac{q_{k^{'},L}}{\lambda_{k^{'}} + q_{k^{'},L}(M_{L} - m_{L})} $  if $\phi_{L}$ happens to be between $d_{L}$ and $D_{L}$ the KKT conditions says $M_{L}, m_{L} =0 $, then
 $\frac{q_{k^{'},L}}{\lambda_{k^{'}}} =  \frac{q_{k,L}}{\lambda_{k}} \Rightarrow \frac{q_{k^{'},L}}{q_{k,L}} = \frac{\lambda_{k^{'}}}{\lambda_{k}}$  which is a contradition because the LHS are a ratio of arbitrary assigned constants, so the ratio depends on L

Comment: I think your subscripts are confusing the problem. Let us say you have $x_{1,L}$, $x_{2,L}$, and $x_{3,L}$. If you choose $k=2$ then what you wrote down is an optimization problem where $x_{1,L}$ and $x_{3,L}$ are fixed and only $x_{2,L}$ is the optimization variable. Even your Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}(x_{k,L})$ implies that for some $k$, $x_{k,L}$ is the variable you are optimizing for and the others are constant. Choosing a different $k$ is essentially solving a different optimization problem. If you are finding the max for $(x_{1,L}, \dots , x_{3,L})$ then your Lagrangian is wrong.

Comment: Oh i see, yeah it got confusing, what i want is to max for all $(x_{1,L}...x_{K,L})$, i'm going to edit it to be more clear.  But how exactly should my lagrangian be then?

Comment: Ok, now the problem makes more sense. Before it looked like you were taking the derivative of $\mathcal{L}$ for some $k$ and not the gradient of $\mathcal{L}$. The remark about $\frac{q_{k^{'},L}}{\lambda_{k^{'}}} =  \frac{q_{k,L}}{\lambda_{k}} \Rightarrow \frac{q_{k^{'},L}}{q_{k,L}} = \frac{\lambda_{k^{'}}}{\lambda_{k}}$ doesn't appear to be a contradiction. All this statement is telling you is that your Lagrange multipliers satisfy some ratio condition. The condition states that $\phi_{L}$ is the same for each dual variable $\lambda_k$.

Comment: But you see, as the ratio with the dual variables does not depend on the choice of L, just of k, then  $ \frac{\lambda_{k^{'}}}{\lambda_{k}} = \frac{q_{k^{'},L}}{q_{k,L}} = \frac{q_{k^{'},L^{'}}}{q_{k,L^{'}}}  $ which is a condition that is almost never true, because $q_{k,L}$ is arbitrarily assigned. So that means that most of the time either $\phi_{L} = d_{L}$ or $\phi_{L} = D_{L}$ by the KKT conditions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109975/discussion-between-asanexerciseprove-and-themathguy-314).